# How to find all of the attributes (name, icon, etc) of .desktop file?

Tags: linux, shell, gtk

I am trying to create an app launcher that uses .desktop files. I wonder what other app launchers use to find said attributes. I thought that maybe I could use `awk`. However, trying to find `name` could show `name[es]` and other foreign languages. I also found a tool `desktoptojson`, which converts a .desktop file to json. However, I wonder if there is a more efficient approach than that.

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard way to do this is, but you could simply loop over each line of the file and compare the start to the attributes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Westman's answer to use `g_app_info_get_all()` was a good one, but I was confused for a long time about how to use the functions.

`g_app_info_get_all` returns a `GList` struct. I found a [reference page](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/glist.html.en) showing how `GList` worked. I adapted its first code snippet to fit `g_app_info_get_all()`:

```
GList *some_list, *l;

some_list = g_app_info_get_all(); /*This is where the GList function goes

for (l = some_list; l != NULL; l = l->next)
  {
    gpointer element_data = l->data;
    printf("%s\n", g_app_info_get_display_name(element_data)); /*print out all of the display names of the .desktop files */
  }
return 0;
```

I put this code into `int main` in a new C file, added `#include <gio/gio.h>`, compiled the file like how any GTK file is compiled (read the manual), and the program outputted every .desktop file's name.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged GTK, I'll give an answer using GLib.

Try [GAppInfo](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html). You can get a list of all applications on the system using `g_app_info_get_all`, then get their names, icons, etc. It can handle localization, and even has methods to launch applications.

It should automatically detect .desktop files in the default locations, but if you want to get a GAppInfo for a particular file, use [g_desktop_app_info_new_from_filename](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-Desktop-file-based-GAppInfo.html#g-desktop-app-info-new-from-filename).

Comment: Good. I don't know how to use a `GAppInfo` or `GList` filename, but I'll try to find a way to use them.

Comment: @AncientStraits Are you writing a shell script or an application?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it all out. I was writing a C application, so once I figured out how to use a CList, it worked perfectly. I will add a more enhanced answer for anyone that is as confused as I was.